# Integral Calculus for Riemann Sums Summation of area of square root x from 0-3

Tags: calculus

I was looking to find the integral from 0 to 3 of f(x) = x^(1/2) for my maths investigation for school. However, I was looking to solve this through a summation of Riemann sums, with a limit of n (the nu,ber of rectangles) approaching infinity. I was able to find an example of how to find the area from 0-1, but I am struggling to be able to use apply this concept to find the area from 0-3.

At the bottom of this page: https://wiki.math.ucr.edu/index.php/Riemann_Sums they solve it from 0-1.

Currently I have a proof that is based off observation that as n approaches infinity, it will reach the exact area. However, I was looking for a mathematical evaluation, and though I understand what they are doing in the article, I'm not sure what part I must do differently to find the area from 0-3 instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: That's not an easy project for school level. Good on you for giving it a go. How do *you* think you can change what they have done in the link so that the lower limit is $0$ and the upper limit is $3$ ?

Comment: Well I understand that they mentioned in the article that their closing and beginning shapes will be squares (since when they reversed the function, and observed x^2, 1^2 = 1 and 0^2 = 0, and mine will not be. I think it has to do with delta x (width) that they are using, which after simplification I will find a different result, but I am unsure what is the difference between their delta x and mine will be

Comment: You can do similar to their example, but change $x_i \to 3x_i.$ You then have to think about what $\ f(3x_i)\ $ is as well, but that isn't difficult. You can then compare to what they did in their calculation and bring the constants outside of the sum and the limit to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the calculation on the website:

\begin{align}\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\, dx = \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\,\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})\cdot\Delta x_{i}\\
\\
=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{n}\cdot\frac{2i-1}{n^{2}}\\
\\
=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2i^{2}-i}{n^{3}}\\
\\
=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}}\left(2\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)\\
\\
=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^{3}}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^{3}}\right)\\
\\
=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\,\left(\frac{4n^{3}}{6n^{3}}+\frac{n^{2}}{2n^{3}}\right)\qquad\qquad(\textrm{for~large~}n)\\
\\
=\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}+0\\
\\
=\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}.
\end{align}

$$$$

They are doing calculations with rectangles of endpoints $\ x_i\ ;\ $ the left-most rectangle has left endpoint $\ x_0=0\ $ and the right-most rectangle has right endpoint at $\ x_n=1.$ Therefore, all you need to do is use rectangle three times the width as in their example, and you're done!

But you must be careful, because you're *not just getting all* of the rectangles in their example and making them three times wider. For example, your left-most rectangle has left endpoint $\ x_0=0\ $ and right endpoint $\ x_1=\frac{3}{n^2},\ $ the next rectangle has left endpoint  $\ x_1=\frac{3}{n^2},\ $ and right endpoint $\ x_2=3 \times \frac{4}{n^2},\ $ etc. So you're using one third the amount of rectangles as they are in their calculation, and these rectangles are three times the width as the ones in the example.

Now we must replace $\ x_i\ $ with $\ 3x_i\ $ which means you also must also replace $\ f(x_i)\ $ with $\ f(3x_i),\ $ which equals $\ \large{\sqrt{3 \frac{i^2}{n^2} } = \sqrt{3}\ \frac{i}{n}}.$

Comparing with their example, this gives us:

\begin{align}
\\
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{x}\, dx = \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\,\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(3x_{i})\cdot\ 3 \Delta x_{i}\\
\\
\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{3}\frac{i}{n}\cdot3 \Delta x_{i}\\
\\
=3\sqrt{3}\ \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})\cdot\Delta x_{i}\qquad (!)\\
\\
=3\sqrt{3}\cdot \frac{2}{3} \qquad \text{using the result from their example}\\
\\
=2\sqrt{3}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much I just finished being able to understand and explain this in my assignment. I never thought to manipulate it in this way, and its really interesting. This has been unbelievably helpful. I will credit you. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. You can credit me by upvoting my answer and also accepting it with the green tick